# How to add viewfinder to google glass app

Tags: google-glass

I am currently trying to make a google glass application and am having trouble figuring out how to add a viewfinder to the CardBuilder for my application. Basically, I am trying to have a camera view along with displaying some data on the screen. I found some stuff online about using .addView() but this is not allowed with CardBuilder. Is there another way to do this?